# Определите типы речевых ошибок в каждом предложении

Tags: стилистика

1. Определите типы речевых ошибок в каждом предложении
2. Произведите стилистическую правку с учетом ее параллельных вариантов.
   1) Это самый добрейший человек из всех, кого я знаю.
   2) Экипаж находится в отличном состоянии.
   3) Миша был виновен в том, что разбил банку с вареньем.
   4) Модель построена в соответствии с известными законами частных наук.
   5) Президент потребовал от министров-силовиков наиболее серьезного отношения к этому преступлению террористов. 
   6) Молодая мама пришла на прием к врачу с ее детьми.
   7) В магазине было куплено несколько пар носок и чулок.
   8) Ряд стульев стояли посередине коридора.
   9) Командировочных расселили в гостинице.
   10) В спорте большое значение играет упорная тренировка, выдержка, упорство.
   11) В их выступлениях чувствовалась уверенность в победе.

Comment: @fargucik, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

1. Применение к прилагательному превосходной степени внешнего элемента превосходной степени (тавтология).
2. Эта неполная по смыслу фраза может подойти к случаям, когда экипаж "отлично подготовлен" или "отдохнул и готов дальше работать". Если же речь о настроении, то надо так и сказать ("в отличном настроении"), возможно даже, "пребывает".
3. Применение излишне формального выражения ("виновен" больше уместно в судебной практике или по более серьёзным случаям).
4. "Модель", скорее всего, должна была вести себя так, чтобы правильно отражать упомянутые законы. Фраза построена так, как если бы эти законы были использованы в качестве пособия для построения модели. Лучше сказать "с учётом" (в модели учтены отдельные законы, в результате она подходит для их описания).
5. Стилистически неудачно употребление слова "наиболее" - обычно так говорят в случае выбора из нескольких альтернатив (напр. серьёзно, очень серьёзно и вполне серьёзно). Правильно сказать "самого". "Преступление террористов" здесь лучше заменить на формальное "террористический акт".
6. Здесь неудачен выбор притяжательной формы местоимения (надо "своими"). Помимо стилистического недостатка, есть вероятнось ошибочного отнесения  "детей" к женщине-врачу.
7. Пара чулок, но пара носков.
8. Вряд ли так неестественно стоял ряд стульев (если привести в единственное число глагол; правильно: "некоторые стулья стояли...").
9. "Расселяют" в разные места, здесь "поселили". В формальном случае (если говорят те, к кому приехали по работе) лучше сказать "командированные". Командировочными называют (например, персонал гостиницы) посторонних людей, откуда-то приехавших по работе.
10. Невозможное словосочетание "играть значение" - глагол взят из устойчивого сочетания "играть роль". Правильно "имее(ю)т".
11. Не обозначено, чья это уверенность: спортсменов в своей победе или наблюдающего за выступлением в их победе.